# TFS Sync history

Tags: tfs

In TFS, how do I see the history of syncs to a workspace? I want to see when I sync'd and which files were changed when the sync occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: you can't.  Sync history is not stored anywhere.

That said...depending on exactly what you what to know, and what assumptions you're willing to make, there's probably a way...

What changeset is my workspace sync'd up thru?  Assumption: you always Get to a consistent snapshot in time, not a label nor a partial Get on some subfolder.  Answer:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory $/ -r -version W -stop 1
```

Which files were updated during the last sync?  Assumption: your last sync took <1min to download.  Answer:

```
$files = dir -r | sort lastwritetime -desc; 
$files | 
    ? { $files[0].lastwritetime - $_.lastwritetime -lt [timespan]::TicksPerMinute } |
    select fullname, lastwritetime
```

(these are Powershell, BTW -- substitute your script language of choice)